# Input Box for Mandatory Data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that basically will make it so that if any data is added to column 3 of any table in my workbook, but no data is added to column 4, an input box will appear and prompt the user to enter the required data. I have been able to find bits and pieces of what I am looking for, but haven't been able to put together a solution that references columns in a structured table. Below is my code best attempt. I have no idea why it doesn't work as I am definitely not a VBA guru (yet!). With that in mind, please be gentle lol. Any and all help appreciated! Thank you!

As a side note, this will be added to a larger set of subs. I have all of those working properly.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim t As ListObjects
    Dim Pos As ListColumns
    myOCC As Variant

    For Each t In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
        If Not Intersect(Target, PosD.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, PosD.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange) <> 0 Then
            myOCC = InputBox("OCC Code Required. Please Enter Valid OCC Code")

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Cells(Target.Row, "C").Value = General
            Application.EnableEvents = True

            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next t
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you thought about using conditional formatting to flag the interior of the cell that is empty to draw attention?  I imagine that, as a user, if multiple boxes need filled in i might not have all of the information available immediately and closing the file, saved with the flags, would allow people to come back once they've found the info.

Comment: 1. Can you clarify what `PosD` is? 2. I'm guessing you want to `Dim t as ListObject`, not `ListObjects`. 3. I think you're missing a `Dim` in front `myOCC As Variant`.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` the variable `General` is not declared and not initialized and therefore empty. So you write nothing into the cells. If you meant it as a string replace it with `"General"`.

Comment: @BigBen PosD is the variable for position description. Forgot the D when I typed it into the original post.

Comment: @Cyril - I want to force them to do it then and there, because otherwise they don't. Been down that road lol. They have the list of occ codes available on another spreadsheet. The occ codes are the most important bit of info on the sheet, so it's vital that they add it.

Comment: @BigBen - There are multiple tables on each sheet, and i want this to apply to all. Does that change whether I use ListObjects vs ListObject?

Comment: `For each t in ActiveSheet.ListObjects` - shouldn't that be `Sh`, not `ActiveSheet` - should be for each `ListObject` in the sheet's collection of `ListObjects`. `For each` iterates over each of them individually.

Comment: @Duck9139 Using a selection change event IN EACH SHEET for column 3, cell moving from cells(i,3) to cells(i,4), you can do a check that if the selection does not move from 3 to 4, they get a popup (a userform) telling them to enter the data, which will go into the location cell(i,4) as i = activecell.row.  That would be a path forward, though you want to iterate through each cellIi,4) in each sheet to retroactively put in the needed info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will force the input box each time a user makes a change to the third column of a list object on any sheet if the fourth column does not have a value. It's probably the quickest and easiest way to absolutely ensure the value gets entered.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If isCellInListObject(Target) Then

        Dim lo As ListObject
        Set lo = Sh.ListObjects(Target.ListObject.Name)

        If Not Intersect(lo.DataBodyRange.Columns(3), Target) Is Nothing Then

            If Target.Offset(, 1) = vbNullString Then

                Dim occ As Variant
                occ = InputBox("OCC Code Required. Please Enter Valid OCC Code")

                Target.Offset(, 1) = occ

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub


Function isCellInListObject(whichCell As Range) As Boolean

    Dim test As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next 'used because a cell not in a list object will produce an error (but test will result in false)
    test = whichCell.ListObject.Name <> ""
    On Error GoTo 0

    isCellInListObject = test

End Function
```